# Why are scrollbars appearing on my site on mobile devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm trying to make a small project site that's responsive using twitter-bootstrap and ember.js.

It looks great on desktop and mostly scales to mobile devices except for one thing: x and y scrollbars appear on my android phone for the page. I don't know if this is the case on iPhone because I don't have one available at the moment.

My site is [here](http://www.eyeglooobservatory.com)

Can anyone see anything obvious in the inspector?

Comment: Not seeing it in Android browser nor Chrome browser in android 4.3, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I tried to look through your css but it was minified. However you are asking for the overflow-y property on the .about class to scroll so that is going to give you scroll bars when the content is more than the containing element.

So I think that .about div is your culprit try to make that div scale with your content without using overflow property. If you have 10 paragraph it will grow with the size for example.

Second it looks as though you were doing alot of css in order to clear floats, think about refactoring. Rather than putting the code repeatedly on all the elements declare one class in your css and just use that class if you have floated elements and the containing div is collapsing.

That is all i could see hope that helps some what.